# Filter list of objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an obejct in below manner

```
public class dettails
    {
        public string server { get; set; }
        public string details1 { get; set; }
        public string details2 { get; set; }
        public string version    { get; set; }

        public dettails(string Server, string Details1, string Details2, string Version)
        {
            server = Server;
            details1 = Details1;
            details2 = Details2;
            version = Version;
        }
    }
```

Following is the data stored in the list of objects.

```
Server1, Database, MySQL, 5.5
Server2, Database, MySQL, 5.1
Server3, OS, Ubuntu, 10.04
Server1, OS, Ubuntu, 10.04
Server2, OS, Ubuntu, 12.04
Server3, Language, Python, 2.6.3
```

The data is already stored in the list of objects. The output I want is in below manner

A list of software package names for which an out-of-date version (i.e. a version which is not the latest version) is installed on at least 2 different servers.

Thus, in this case, the output of your program should be:

Ubuntu Because Ubuntu 10.04 is an out-of-date version (the latest version is 12.04), and it is installed on two servers (Server 3, and Server 1).

How can i achieve it using linq. Please advice.

Comment: Have you tried anything, or are you just asking us to do your work for you? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I had tried traversing the script using foreach and comparing, but it was was taking a lot of time. SO, i thought of going to linq. I am new to linq.

Comment: @Ankur Then why didn't you post what you tried?

Comment: I would recommend keeping version in a designated class, containing x integers (usually it's 3 or 4). That would help you figure out the order of the versions.

Comment: I deleted that code yesterday. I dont have it with me. Sorry :(. Shouldnt have deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a way of finding out what the most recent version for each operating system is. Without that information it is kind of hard to pull off.

We could pretend that the newest version we find on any of the servers is the "most recent version", but that is not really accurate.

If we have a way of generating a unique key, let us say:

```
string AssemlbeKey(dettails serverInfo) => $"{serverInfo.details1}, {serverInfo.details2}";
```

Then we can build a dictionary to determine the newest version installed on any of the servers in the given collection:

```
var dictPretendedMostRecentVersionsByDetails = ServerCollection
    .GroupBy(entry => AssembleKey(entry))
    .ToDictionary(
        group => group.Key, 
        group => group.Value
            .OrderByDescending(entry => Version.Parse(entry.version))
            .First()
    );
```

Now that we have a sense of what is "deprecated", we can scan the server collection for it.

```
var deprecatedCollection = ServerCollection
    .Select(entry => new KeyValuePair<string, ServerInfo>(AssembleKey(entry), entry)
    .Where(entry => dictPretendedMostRecentVersionsByDetails[entry.Key] < Version.Parse(entry.version))
    .Select(entry => entry.Value);
```

Then you should have a collection of deprecated server details and now can enumerate over it and do whatever you want to do with it (for example writing it to the console with all necessary informations).